# How to read char/string one by one from a file and compare in C

Tags: c, linux

this is my first time asking questions here. I'm currently learning C and Linux at the same time. I'm working on a simple c program that use system call only to read and write files. My problem now is, how can I read the file and compare the string/word are the same or not. An example here like this:

foo.txt contains：

```
hi
bye
bye
hi
hi
```

And bar.txt is empty.

After I do:

```
./myuniq foo.txt bar.txt
```

The result in bar.txt will be like:

```
hi
bye
hi
```

The result will just be like when we use uniq in Linux.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_MAX 256

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int wfd,rfd;
    size_t n;
    char temp[LINE_MAX];
    char buf[LINE_MAX];
    char buf2[LINE_MAX];
    char *ptr=buf;

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Invalid useage: ./excutableFileName readFromThisFile writeToThisFile\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rfd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if(rfd==-1){
        printf("Unable to read the file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    wfd=open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(wfd==-1){
        printf("Unable to write to the file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while(n = read(rfd,buf,LINE_MAX)){
        write(wfd,buf,n);
    }

    close(rfd);
    close(wfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above will do the reading and writing with no issue. But I can't really figure out how to read char one by one in C style string under what condition of while loop.

I do know that I may need a pointer to travel inside of buf to find the next line '\n' and something like:

```
while(condi){
    if(*ptr == '\n'){
    strcpy(temp, buf);
    strcpy(buf, buf2);
    strcpy(buf2, temp);
}
else
    write(wfd,buf,n);

    *ptr++;
}
```

But I might be wrong since I can't get it to work. Any feedback might help. Thank you.

And again, it only can be use system call to accomplish this program. I do know there is a easier way to use FILE and fgets or something else to get this done. But that's not the case.

Comment: There are many approaches to solving this problem.  The majority of practical approaches involve storing all the strings in memory.  A very simple one is to read all lines into an array, sort it, and then walk through one word at a time, only outputting a word if it's different from the previous word.  Another approach is to store in some kind of set like a hash map or search tree.  The benefit of that is you can output the words in their original order fairly easily.  I think the `uniq` command in Linux actually requires elements to be sorted as a precondition.

Comment: I might have over-thought the problem here.  Indeed, `uniq` does expect sorted data and so it only compares the current line with the previous.  You already have buffers configured to assist.  You can use `fgets` to read a whole line.  There's no need to read one character at a time.

Comment: Ouch! Using `open()` and `read()` makes this much more difficult that using `fopen()` and `fgets()`. You could even get by with `scanf()` (though not recommended).

Comment: Kuma, Read 1 byte at a time into a buffer until `'\n'`.  Compare that _line_ to the prior line and write accordingly.

Comment: When you call `read(rfd, buf, n)`, up to `n` bytes are read into `buf`. So `read(rfd, buf, LINE_MAX)` reads up to `LINE_MAX` characters. `read(rfd, buf, 3)` would read up to 3 characters. And `read(rfd, buf, 1)` would read one character, it there is one available (that is, you're not at the end of the file). Isn't that enough to write the code? (Although it's certainly not the most efficient solution.)

Comment: @paddy This program is for beginner so I don't think it has to go that deep. It will be somewhat like uniq does but not the exactly work the same. I should say it in this way sorry. But thank you for your advise. And yes fgets will work but doesn't allowed to use this this program.

Comment: Then follow @chux-ReinstateMonica advice. simply use `fgetc()` to read a character at a time saving them in a buffer (character array) until you read a `'\n'` or `EOF`. If it is the first word you read, write it to the file (and write a `'\n'`). Copy the word to a `last` buffer and read the next word. Now compare the `current` and `last` words, if they differ - write `current` to file and copy `current` to `last`.  Too bad you can use `fgets()` makes it much easier. There is a non-POSIX end-of-file corner-case (no `'\n'` after the last line) that you check if using `fgets()`.

Comment: @rici Like chux-ReinstateMonica said I sort of understand I'll need to read 1 byte at a time into a buffer until '\n' is found. So there is no efficient will be consider at this time already. I just so silly that can't really think of how to read it one at the time. But your suggestion have given me some though now...I might give it a try again. Thank you.

Comment: If you have to use `open()` and `read()` and `write()`, you can `read()` 1-character at a time instead of using `fgetc()` -- which is probably off limits if `fgets()` is off limits. There is no inefficiency in reading a single-character at a time. There is a low-level read-buffer provided for I/O of 8192 bytes on Linux (512 bytes on windows), so whether you read 1 or 1000 characters, there is no more disk I/O involved.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'll have a good night if I could use 'fgets()' I will try to play with it since rici and chux-ReinstateMonica gave me some though now. But thank you for advise too.

Comment: Kuma, If you want to handle _all_ input, do not use C _strings_.  Instead use a count of characters in a buffer - not a _null character_ terminated string.  This then properly deals with reading a null character.  Such concern is unlikely in a HW assignment, yet makes for more robust code out in the wild.

Comment: Kuma, Also be clear about the difference between a _line_ and _string_.  The file has lines (characters up to and including a potential final `'\n'`) and C has strings (characters up to and including a final  `'\0'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use the `read` and `write` system calls, you will have to build an abstraction around them, as they have no notion of lines, words, or characters. Semantically, they deal purely with bytes.

Reading arbitrarily-sized chunks of the file would require us to sift through looking for line breaks. This would mean tokenizing the data in our buffer, as you have somewhat shown. A problem occurs when our buffer ends with a partial line. We would need to make adjustments so our next `read` call concatenates the rest of the line.

To keep things simple, instead, we might consider reading the file one byte at a time.

A decent (if naive) way to begin is by essentially reimplementing the rough functionally of `fgets`. Here we read a single byte at a time into our buffer, at the current offset. We end when we find a newline character, or when we would no longer have enough room in the buffer for the null-terminating character.

Unlike `fgets`, here we return the length of our string.

```
size_t read_a_line(char *buf, size_t bufsize, int fd)
{
    size_t offset = 0;

    while (offset < (bufsize - 1) && read(fd, buf + offset, 1) > 0)
        if (buf[offset++] == '\n')
            break;

    buf[offset] = '\0';

    return offset;
}
```

To mimic `uniq`, we can create two buffers, as you have, but initialize their contents to empty strings. We take two additional pointers to manipulate later.

```
char buf[LINE_MAX] = { 0 };
char buf2[LINE_MAX] = { 0 };
char *flip = buf;
char *flop = buf2;
```

After opening our files for reading and writing, our loop begins. We continue this loop as long as we read a nonzero-length string.

If our current string does not match our previously read string, we write it to our output file. Afterwards, we swap our pointers. On the next iteration, from the perspective of our pointers, the secondary buffer now contains the previous line, and the primary buffer is overwritten with the current line.

Again, note that our initial previously read line is the empty string.

```
size_t length;

while ((length = read_a_line(flip, LINE_MAX, rfd))) {
    if (0 != strcmp(flip, flop))
        write(wfd, flip, length);

    swap_two_pointers(&flip, &flop);
}
```

Our pointer swapping function.

```
void swap_two_pointers(char **a, char **b) {
    char *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

---

Some notes:

- The contents of our file-to-be-read should never contains a line that would exceed `LINE_MAX` (including the newline character). We do not handle this situation, which is admittedly a sidestep, as this is the problem we wanted to avoid with the chunking method.
- `read_a_line` should not be passed `NULL` or `0`, to its first and second arguments. An exercise for the reader to figure out why that is.
- `read_a_line` does not really handle `read` failing in the middle of a line.

Comment: Probably conceptually easier to simply copy `buf1` to `buf2` (or `current` to `last`) rather than swapping pointers. You avoid the copy swapping pointers, but that may be a bit of a stretch for a new C user to grasp.  Good approach though.

Comment: Thank you, it works well other than I have problem with the 'swap' function again. I tried to create that function and use it at the first place but I ran into error like `'expected 'car **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[256]'` again. I guess it must have something to do with my `define LINE_MAX 256`. I just use `strcpy()`  to do the swapping. But Thank you again!

Comment: Aside: When dealing with `size_t` math `(offset + 1) < bufsize` is better than `offset < (bufsize - 1)` to cope with extreme cases like when `bufsize == 0`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! The error, @Kuma, would have been from trying to swap the arrays themselves  (e.g., `swap_two_pointers(&buf, &buf2)`), instead of using the plain pointers (`flip` & `flop`). I do agree this was a somewhat advanced concept, so well done making the adjustment to just copy the buffer contents instead.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one buffer that stores whatever the previous line contained.

The way this works for the *current* line is that before you add a character you test whether what you're adding is the same as what's already in there.  If it's different, then the current line is marked as unique.  When you reach the end of the line, you then know whether to output the buffer or not.

Implementing the above idea using standard input for simplicity (but it doesn't really matter how you read your characters):

```
int len = 0;
int dup = 0;
for (int c; (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF; )
{
    // Check for duplicate and store
    if (dup && buf[len] != c)
        dup = 0;
    buf[len++] = c;

    // Handle end of line
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        if (dup) printf("%s", buf);
        len = 0;
        dup = 1;
    }
}
```

See here that we use the `dup` flag to represent whether a line is duplicated.  For the first line, clearly it is not, and all subsequent lines start off with the assumption they are duplicates.  Then the only possibility is to remain a duplicate or be detected as unique when one character is different.

The comparison before store is actually avoiding tests against uninitialized buffer values too, by way of short-circuit evaluation.  That's all managed by the `dup` flag -- you only test if you know the buffer is already good up to this point:

```
if (dup && buf[len] != c)
    dup = 0;
```

That's basically all you need.  Now, you should definitely add some sanity to prevent buffer overflow.  Or you may wish to use a dynamic buffer that grows as necessary.

An entire program that operates on standard I/O streams, plus handles arbitrary-length lines might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    size_t capacity = 15, len = 0;
    char *buf = malloc(capacity);
    
    for (int c, dup = 0; (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF || len > 0; )
    {
        // Grow buffer
        if (len == capacity)
        {
            capacity = (capacity * 2) + 1;
            char *newbuf = realloc(buf, capacity);
            if (!newbuf) break;
            buf = newbuf;
            dup = 0;
        }

        // NUL-terminate end of line, update duplicate-flag and store
        if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
            c = '\0';
        if (dup && buf[len] != c)
            dup = 0;
        buf[len++] = c;

        // Output line if not a duplicate, and reset
        if (!c)
        {
            if (!dup)
                printf("%s\n", buf);
            len = 0;
            dup = 1;
        }
    }

    free(buf);
}
```

Demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/GzGz3nxMK

Comment: Since I must use system calls, I'll go for @Oka's answer. But Thank you so much!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The loop condition includes `|| len > 0` which is why the EOF test is there -- this handles either end-of-line or end-of-input, treating both as a whole line (although some may argue it is not the same thing).

Comment: @Kuma sure, no problem.  Nice to be spoiled for choice.  I understood that your requirement was to do this operation one character at a time.  _How_ those characters are read is unimportant.  I said as much when I wrote the answer.  Happy coding!

Comment: @paddy - my bad, you indeed had that one handled. Lack of sleep is never good for details...

Comment: Haha nah it doesn't help that I have a messy for-loop.  It would've been clearer as a `while` like I wrote in the first snippet.  Oh... I didn't?  Now who needs sleep ;)  I thought I did.  Well, it would've been clearer.